# Input 0 of layer sequential_13 incompatible with the layer: expected axis-1 inputshape to have value 3 but received input with shape (None, 30, 90, 1)

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, vgg-net

I am working on an image classification problem for detecting faulty LED lights, and have my own custom dataset, I am using transfer learning from Pre-trained VGG16, it is throwing me an error of shape when I do .fit,  'ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_13 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 3 but received input with shape (None, 30, 90, 1).', pretrained_model = VGG16, and then trying to add Dense layers. Please help! Thank you!

```
X = np.array(X).reshape(-1, 30, 90, 1 )
y = np.array(y)
X.shape   --------> (4349, 30, 90, 1)

pretrained_model = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape= (224,224,3))


new_model = tf.keras.models.Sequential(pre_trained_model.layers)
new_model.add(Flatten())
new_model.add(Dense(300, activation = 'relu'))
new_model.add(Dense(100, activation = 'relu'))
new_model.add(Dropout(0.2))
new_model.add(Dense(4, activation = 'softmax'))
```

Answer (score 0):

`pretrained_model = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape= (224,224,3))` shows that the model is defined for color images, but you're passing greyscale images `(4349, 30, 90, 1)` to the model. You can convert the image array to three dimensions:

```
X = np.stack((X,)*3, axis=1)
```

Or you can iterate through each image and make a new array with the new color image:

```
color_images = []
for i in X:
    color_images.append(cv2.cvtColor(i, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB))
X = np.asarray(color_images)
```

Comment: I just tried this and it is throwing me another error: **ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 2 from 1 for '{{node sequential_15/block5_pool/MaxPool}} = MaxPool[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", explicit_paddings=[], ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding="VALID", strides=[1, 2, 2, 1]](sequential_15/block5_conv3/Relu)' with input shapes: [?,1,5,512].
**

Comment: After the convolutional layers (or pooling), you have pixel values that will be less than 0. You can't have a negative pixel value, or you can't have an operation that will create negative pixel values to use. You need to pad. You see where it says `padding="VALID"`? That means no padding. It needs to be `padding="SAME"` or increase your input image size.